# Скачивание Google Sheets при изменении

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet

Имеется Google Sheets, в которой время от времени происходят изменения. Мне нужно скачать Google Sheets в формате xlsx, после совершённых изменений. Я не знаю как всё время следить за статусом таблицы. Пытался разобраться сам, но не получилось.

Comment: Разве в API нельзя получить время последнего изменения таблицы?

Comment: Ну так и обращайтесь каждые несколько минут (надо посмотреть лимиты) и сверяйте время.

Comment: Попробуй это: каждые, например, 60 секунд, загружай себе в переменную ```info``` последнюю строку таблицы, и сверяй ее с переменной ```info_prev```, если они не равны, то произошли изменения, если равны - делай ```info_prev = info```; ну и это всё в ```while```. Можешь вместо всей строки сохранять только первичный ключ...